# Borderlands 2 save game corrupted on ps5

Tags: borderlands-2, ps5

I was playing borderlands 2 on TVHM on my PS5. I had saved my game 2 days ago before starting the tiny tina DLC (Ii had reached level 55 at this point). Today all of a sudden my game crashed when I was grinding the murderlin's temple. On starting the game it told me that the data is corrupted as shown below. By this time I had completed Tiny Tina DLC and all side quests and was moving on to other DLCs.

[image]

When I used the cross-save feature to download the data that I saved 2 days ago all my tina DLC progress was lost. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

This has happened to me before, when the PS Plus upgrade happened this summer. I was traveling for 3 months. Before traveling I had finished TVHM and when I came back my save file mysteriously told me that my TVHM progress is lost. I was really disappointed since I was looking forward to really play this game after coming back from vacation. For the 2nd time this game really disappointed me, I liked it so much but I guess it would be good to let it go for good this time. If someone encountered this, please help!

Comment: I've no idea if the cross save will allow you to move a character/save from PC to Playstation. If it does and you don't mind "cheating" the system to get what you lost back, try this [BL2 save editor](https://github.com/gibbed/Gibbed.Borderlands2/releases). You'll want "bl2_saveedit_1.0.46.zip."

Comment: i am not playing on my PC and my saves are not there on PC either